# inheritance in objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i am new to objective C.is it possible multiple ,multilevel,hybrid,hierarchical,all types of inheritance in objective C?

(Translation:  What kind of inheritance does Objective-C support?)

Answer (score 10):

No.  Objective-C supports single inheritance.

You can declare multiple inheritance intentions through protocols, but you'll need to provide implementations per conforming class.

Categories allow for the extension of an existing class, but do not allow for the extension of multiple classes simultaneously.

I would suggest that you start here:

[Introduction to The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

Comment: This question was flagged for deletion, to be honest, I do not understand it. Can you edit it into something coherent?

Answer (score 5):

No multiple inheritance of implementation in Objective C. As an alternative, consider [categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).  Not sure what you mean by multilevel, hybrid or hierarchical in this context. What are your actual NEEDS, as opposed to, a bunch of buzzwords...?-)